# Change Width and Height of Login with Facebook Popup Window

Tags: php, html, css, facebook

How do i change width and height of Login with Facebook popup window? By default it is displaying a popup of 450x260 px so we cannot see the login form (captures attached). How do i change the size of the popup window?

Default Popup Size, Login Form is not seen here:
[image: Default Popup Size, Login Form is not seen here]

We need to resize it so we can see the login form:
[image: We need to resize it so we can see the login form]

I have tried solutions suggested in [FB.ui and setting popup size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948517/fb-ui-and-setting-popup-size) with no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my complete code:

```
<?php
session_start();
define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'myidhere');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', 'mysecrethere');

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret)
{ 
    $signed_request = parse_signed_request(@$_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id], $app_secret);
    $signed_request['uid'] = $signed_request['user_id']; // for compatibility 
    if (!is_null($signed_request))
    {
        $access_token_response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$app_id&redirect_uri=&client_secret=$app_secret&code={$signed_request['code']}");
        parse_str($access_token_response);
        $signed_request['access_token'] = $access_token;
        $signed_request['expires'] = time() + $expires;
    }
    return $signed_request;
}

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret)
{
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input)
{
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . YOUR_APP_ID]))
{ 
    $cookie = get_facebook_cookie(YOUR_APP_ID, YOUR_APP_SECRET);
    $user = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .$cookie['access_token']));
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Facebook Login Connect for Website Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (@$cookie)
{
    ?>
    <h2>You Are Logged In <?= $user->name ?> </h2> <br />
    E-mail ID: <?= $user->email ?>
    <br />
    <a href="javascript://" onclick="FB.logout(function() { window.location='sandbox/facebook_login' }); return false;" >Logout</a>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <h2>Welcome Guest! </h2>    
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:login-button perms="email" width="width_value" show_faces="true" autologoutlink="true" size="large">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
    <?php
} ?>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>   
<script>
 // Initiate FB Object
 FB.init({
   appId: '<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>', 
   status: true,
   cookie: true, 
   xfbml: true
   });
 // Reloading after successfull login
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { 
    window.location.reload(); 
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see why i got downvoted for this?

Comment: Ouch.
It seems like a bug since i just noticed that it only happen on my Firefox and works perfectly fine in Chrome, it seems like the window doesn't automatically grow in Firefox, i misstated the problem.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/434461713241383/

Comment: Might have to do with your/the user’s JavaScript settings in Firefox. If the Option _“Allow Scripts to: [ ] Move or resize popup windows”_ is disabled, then there is probably no way around that for Facebooks script (expect opening the popup in a “large enough” size from the beginning).

Comment: Sadly that's not what happened in my case, but that's a handy knowledge, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with Mozilla Firefox which made the autoGrow didn't work. When i upgraded to Mozilla Firefox 16.0.2 the problem resolves automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try manipulating the height attribute of the dom with jquery

```
$('[whatever dom element]').attr([modify attributes]);
```